# SQL correct check for NOT EQUAL TO NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I used `<>` and `!=` to test `NOT EQUAL TO` in SQL. I tried below syntaxes, all failed except `IS NOT NULL`.

What is the correct way of checking `NOT EQUAL with NULL`

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=null

SELECT COUNT(*) 

FROM Emp_Details

WHERE [source_id] IS NOT null -- gives 1289 records


SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM Emp_Details

WHERE [source_id] != null  -- gives 0 records

SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM Emp_Details

WHERE [source_id] <> null  -- gives 0 records


SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM Emp_Details

WHERE [source_id] <> @p1 -- gives 0 records
```

The below condition is never executed for me, even i pass `0 or 1 for @p1`

```
  IF COALESCE ( @p1, NULL ) != NULL  
  BEGIN  
   DELETE  
   FROM @EmpDetailTable  
   WHERE [source_id] != @p1
  END
```

Note: some of the `source_id` values are NULL

Comment: Obviously the one giving you results ;)

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` or `IS NULL` are checks for null

Comment: `NULL` is the absent of a value.  The `<>` and `!=` require a value, so when comparing to `NULL` they evaluate to `undefined` (false). For more details check [Handling Null Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't know whether it is correct or not, but my seniors taught me to use `ISNULL(source_id,0)!=0`(if it is integer) or `ISNULL(source_id,'')!=''`(if it is varchar) which doesn't give precise answer yet cant be just ignored...

Comment: Different systems handle it differently. Some return `false`. SQL server specifically returns `UNKNOWN` if either or both sides of a comparision is NULL.

Comment: No system returns false for `(expression = NULL)`. They all return `UNKNOWN` (or `NULL`).

Comment: @Vitap Ramdevputra, the problem with that approach is that it does not evaluate to a `searchable` expression, meaning if `source_id` has an index it will be ignored and potentially cause a full table scan.  The correct approach is `source_id != '' and source_id is not null`.

Comment: Why this much effort to avoid `NOT NULL` comparison? Any special reason for not to use `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 4):

The common ways to check if an expression is not null, are the `IS NOT NULL` and `IS NULL`:

```
 WHERE (expression IS NOT NULL)
```

or:

```
 WHERE NOT (expression IS NULL)
```

There is also the `IS DISTINCT FROM` operator but not all DBMS have implemented it:

```
 WHERE (expression IS DISTINCT FROM NULL)
```

---

The code:

```
IF COALESCE ( @p1, NULL ) != NULL  
BEGIN  
 DELETE  
 FROM @EmpDetailTable  
 WHERE [source_id] != @p1
END
```

if you mean to be executed only when `@p1` is not null, can be written as below:

```
IF @p1 IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN  
 DELETE  
 FROM @EmpDetailTable  
 WHERE [source_id] != @p1
END
```

Comment: Updated my question with the actual problem

Comment: I have applied same logic to other column filters, like `IF COALESCE ( @p_status_id, NULL ) != NULL` all works fine. The only difference with this column is it has NULL values, where other columns not has NULL

Comment: Could you please explain the diffrences of those two condition filters  and why i should apply `IS NOT NULL` only for `source_id` ?

Comment: What do you mean that `IF COALESCE ( @p2, NULL ) != NULL` works fine? The `BEGIN ... END` will never be activated.

Comment: You are correct, they also not working. My mistake .. update my question

Answer (score 2):

`IS NOT null` is the correct way.

As the `Remarks` section of [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174065.aspx) link say that "Comparison operators return UNKNOWN if either or both arguments are NULL." SO We can't depend on `Comparison Operators`.

Comment: why other operator like <> or != cannot be used?

Comment: @Murali: Because the SQL standard states that nothing is equal to NULL. NULL is not a value, and thus can't be compared.

Comment: @Murali: I provided link to the "Microsoft" site for the exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare with NULL try it

```
select * where id = null
select * where id != null
```

The examples above returns all rows!

you must use is null

```
select * where id is null
select * where id is not null
```

There's a common misconception about null. It don't mean "nothing" it mean "I don't know, lack of data" and translates to english more less like "whatever" or "anything".

Comment: +1 the <> and != operators compares actual values. NULL is not a value, so when it tries to compare, it results in 0 records returned. NULL and '' is 2 different things. If you were working with '', you could have != and <>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IS NOT null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174065.aspx)

```
To determine whether an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead 
of comparison operators, such as = or !=. Comparison operators return UNKNOWN 
if either or both arguments are NULL.
```

---

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=null

SELECT COUNT(*) 

FROM Emp_Details

WHERE [source_id] IS NOT null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one:

```
IF COALESCE(@p1, NULL) IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN  
  DELETE  
  FROM @EmpDetailTable  
  WHERE [source_id] != @p1
END
```

Comment: IMHO, `COALESCE(@p1, NULL)` is pointless, it's equivalent to just `@p1`.

Comment: You're right, but I wanted to modify his code as few as necessary and it was all about this IS NOT NULL comparison. So I left it in there even if it is useless in his example.